# Versionamento SQL Server integrado ao Entity Framework

Tags: sql-server, versionamento

Na empresa que trabalho optaram por criar os modelos a partir do banco de dados com o `Entity Power Tools`.

Temos uma versão online da nossa aplicação e as locais para teste e desenvolvimento.

Quando necessário alterar algo nos modelos, alteramos no banco e geramos os modelos denovo... até ai tudo bem, usamos versionamento e todo mundo fica com os modelos iguais.

O problema é as alterações no banco, por exemplo:

> Um campo VALOR_NOTA era double agora passou a ser decimal

Dai temos que fazer essa alteração no SQL de todas as máquinas.

**Existe uma forma de fazer um versionamento da estrutura de uma tabela no SQL Server?**

Comment: Não é mais fácil vocês usarem *Migrations*? Aí o versionamento do banco fica no código da aplicação.

Comment: Já sugeri com pesquisas e provas, aceitaram a dica mas somente após a finalização do prospecto. Então terei que aguardar!

Comment: Olha, existir existe. O problema é mapear essas mudanças de estrutura. Há uns 5 anos atrás escrevi uma ferramenta em Python que lia um repositório SVN com a estrutura e gerava os scripts de mudança de versão, mas dava muito trabalho e era muito demorado. A gente versionava scripts SQL com a declaração da tabela. Era o que dava pra fazer.

Comment: hum... boa ideia, da pra colocar as declarações em um SQL e versionar dai eu crio uma macro pra executar elas a um clique já me ajuda! Vou esperar alguém pode saber uma forma... Caso ninguém apareça como devo fechar a pergunta?

Comment: Eu respondo pra você. Só queria validar algumas coisas.

Comment: @CiganoMorrisonMendez como movo essa conversa para um chat? Gostaria de perguntar algumas coisas sobre o migrations se possível!

Comment: Vamos [continuar esta discuss&#227;o no bate-papo](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/16871/discussion-between-cigano-morrison-mendez-and-trxplz0).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

O melhor seria usar *Migrations*, mas conforme o autor da pergunta pediu por não ser possível, vou sugerir uma solução alternativa.

Ao gerar suas *Migrations*, execute um `Update-Database` imediatamente com o seguinte comando:

```
Update-Database -Verbose
```

Isso fará o SQL executado ser mostrado no Console. Salve esse Log dentro de algum diretório do projeto com a extensão `.sql`.

Ao publicar seu projeto, execute as *Migrations* em ordem. O resultado deve ser muito semelhanto ao do Entity Framework automatizado.